# I have a bug when converting decimal value using value from spinner

Tags: java, android

I have a simple converter app. Spinners have the same units. I think i wrote everything properly, but it only works when i comment the rest of the code and use only first case, where  i convert cubic millimetres (mm3) to whatever unit from the second spinner. When I include other cases too, it writes incorrect values.

Couple things to know: "valv1" is an editText where i enter value in numbers and "valv3" is simple textView where i write this value. I didnt want to let the user edit the result value, because i didnt know how to do a 2-way conversion.

this is where i define my variables for positions from my spinners, i know i could use "pos1" and "pos2" straight away, but it was easier for me like this, im a total beginner.

```
    switch (a){
case 1: if(b==1){ double mm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
                    valv3.setText(String.valueOf(mm31));
                }
        if(b==2){ double mm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
                    double cm3= mm31*0.001;
                    valv3.setText(String.valueOf(cm3));
                }
        if(b==3){ double mm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
            double dm3= mm31*0.000001;
            valv3.setText(String.valueOf(dm3));
        }
        if(b==4){ double mm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
            double m3= mm31*0.000000001;
            valv3.setText(String.valueOf(m3));
        }
        if(b==5){ double mm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
            double ml= mm31*0.001;
            valv3.setText(String.valueOf(ml));
        }
        if(b==6){ double mm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
            double cl= mm31*0.0001;
            valv3.setText(String.valueOf(cl));
        }
        if(b==7){ double mm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
            double dl= mm31*0.00001;
            valv3.setText(String.valueOf(dl));
        }
        if(b==8){ double mm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
            double l= mm31*0.000001;
            valv3.setText(String.valueOf(l));
        }
        if(b==9){ double mm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
            double hl= mm31*0.00000001;
            valv3.setText(String.valueOf(hl));
        }
```

this takes care of the first value in my first spinner and it works fine. but problems occur when I add the rest of the codes, for other positions from first spinner

```
case 2:
    if(b==1){ double cm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
    double mm32= cm31*1000;
    valv3.setText(String.valueOf(mm32));
    }
    if(b==2){ double cm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
    double cm32= cm31*1;
    valv3.setText(String.valueOf(cm32));
    }
    if(b==3){ double cm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
    double dm3= cm31*0.001;
    valv3.setText(String.valueOf(dm3));
    }
    if(b==4){ double cm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
    double m3= cm31*0.000001;
    valv3.setText(String.valueOf(m3));
    }
    if(b==5){ double cm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
    double ml= cm31*1;
    valv3.setText(String.valueOf(ml));
    }
    if(b==6){ double cm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
    double cl= cm31*0.1;
    valv3.setText(String.valueOf(cl));
    }
    if(b==7){ double cm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
    double dl= cm31*0.01;
    valv3.setText(String.valueOf(dl));
    }
    if(b==8){ double cm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
    double l= cm31*0.001;
    valv3.setText(String.valueOf(l));
    }
    if(b==9){ double cm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
    double hl= cm31*0.00001;
    valv3.setText(String.valueOf(hl));
    }


  case 3:   
    if(b==1){ double dm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
    double mm32= dm31*1000000;
    valv3.setText(String.valueOf(mm32));
    }
    if(b==2){ double dm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
    double cm32= dm31*1000;
    valv3.setText(String.valueOf(cm32));
    }
    if(b==3){ double dm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
    double dm3= dm31*1;
    valv3.setText(String.valueOf(dm3));
    }
    if(b==4){ double dm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
    double m3= dm31*0.001;
    valv3.setText(String.valueOf(m3));
    }
    if(b==5){ double dm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
    double ml= dm31*1000;
    valv3.setText(String.valueOf(ml));
    }
    if(b==6){ double dm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
    double cl= dm31*100;
    valv3.setText(String.valueOf(cl));
    }
    if(b==7){ double dm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
    double dl= dm31*10;
    valv3.setText(String.valueOf(dl));
    }
    if(b==8){ double dm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
    double l= dm31*1;
    valv3.setText(String.valueOf(l));
    }
    if(b==9){ double dm31= Double.valueOf(valv1.getText().toString());
    double hl= dm31*0.01;
    valv3.setText(String.valueOf(hl));
    }
```

and it goes on.. until last case - case 9

my spinner values are here:

```
 <string-array name="volume1">
    <item>mm3</item>
    <item>cm3</item>
    <item>dm3</item>
    <item>m3</item>
    <item>ml</item>
    <item>cl</item>
    <item>dl</item>
    <item>l</item>
    <item>hl</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do, it is not very clear in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you wrote your switch statement incorrectly.
You should have a break statement at the end of each case.
Look at the syntax for java switch statements here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Omg, thanks, you totally saved me.
I will go get my eyes fixed...
Thank you so much!